# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin') when using git bash on windows

Tags: git, npm, git-bash

When I am using Git Bash on windows, and try to do npm commands, I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')
```

Until 2 days ago it was not a problem, and when I am using cmd or powershell it works just fine.

Tried to clone the repos again, did not work.
Tried to delete node modules and package-log.json, did not work.
Tried to clear cache, did not work.

Edit: I lowered Node version and it worked for now, but still interesting why it happend.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was due to the console type, specifically `git bash`. Changing it to `powershell` solved this issue for me.

Comment: I had a similar issue because there was an auto update of my git. I reinstall the latest version of git alongside with git bash, and it works again

Answer (score 1):

You can try these methods for it:

- Check that Node.js is installed correctly by running the command `node -v` in your terminal. If Node.js is not installed, download and install it from the official Node.js website.
- Clear the npm cache by running the command `npm cache clean --force` in your terminal.
- Delete the **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file in your project directory.
- Run the command `npm install --legacy-peers` or `npm install --force` to reinstall the packages for your project.
- If the issue persists, try updating npm to the latest version by running the command `npm install -g npm`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can try to use **npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"** it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in IntelliJ Terminal  - simply solved by opening package.json and clicking "Run" next to the

' "dev"  : ... '  code line.

I don't know why neither Terminal nor PowerShell wouldn't execute the command.
Thought it was and IDE issue, but from all the other comments here, sounds like it could be something else.
Anyway, starting it "manually" with the click on the button worked  ¯_(ツ)_/¯